# Sinatra on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack

I have problems adding sinatra as rack middleware for rails 5. The issue is that once I add `gem "sinatra"` to Rails Gemfile I cannot get the server running. But `bundle install` still finishes without errors. Could someone please explain to me how to add a (middleware) Sinatra App on Rails 5?

Answer (score 1):

Rails will automatically `require` all gems in the gemfile, which is not ideal when using Sinatra as a middleware. This is documented on the Sinatra website [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps).

A workaround to this is changing your Gemfile to say `gem "sinatra", :require => false` then adding `require "sinatra/base"` to your app where it is needed.